# Can't dispatch to jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

I'm trying to run my program but it seems that after it post to servlet, it just stops there and won't dispatch to the next page, just a blank page with the url on PurchaseCreate. I need your help please.

My servlet is under controller folder that is under source packages, JSP is under Web Application -> Web Pages -> MemberAccess, HTML is under Web Application -> Web Pages

Servlet:

```
   public class PurchaseCreate extends HttpServlet {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
    @Resource
    UserTransaction utx;
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
         Members member = new Members();
            Stocks stock = new Stocks();
            Purchase purc = new Purchase();
            String purcid = null;
            String stockid = null;
            String purcdid = null;
            int quantity = 0 ;
            try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {


            int idNum = GeneratePdid();
            if(idNum<10)
                 purcdid = "PD0000"+idNum;
            else if(idNum<100)
                 purcdid = "PD000"+idNum;       
            else if(idNum<1000)
                 purcdid = "PD00"+idNum;
            else if(idNum<10000)
                 purcdid = "PD0"+idNum;
            else if(idNum<100000)
                 purcdid = "PD"+idNum;
            int PidNum = GeneratePid();
            if(PidNum<10)
                 purcid = "P000"+PidNum;
            else if(PidNum<100)
                 purcid = "P00"+PidNum;       
            else if(PidNum<1000)
                 purcid = "P0"+PidNum;
            else if(PidNum<10000)
                 purcid = "P"+PidNum;


            stockid = request.getParameter("stockid");
            stock.setStockid(stockid);
            purc.setPurchaseid(purcid);
            List<Stocks> listPrice = getStock(stockid);
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantity"));
            Purchasedetails purchased = new Purchasedetails(purcdid,quantity,stock,purc);

            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("purchased", purchased);
            session.setAttribute("listPrice", listPrice);

            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/MemberAccess/PurchaseCreateM.jsp");
               rd.forward(request, response);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PurchaseCreate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
    }
 public List<Stocks> getStock(String stockid){
     Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT * FROM Stocks s WHERE s.stockid = :stockid").setParameter("stockid", stockid);
     List<Stocks> stockPrice = query.getResultList();
        return  stockPrice;
 }

public int GeneratePid(){  
            Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Purchase.findAll");
            List<Purchase> purchaseList = query.getResultList();
            String lastId = null;

                    if(!purchaseList.isEmpty()){
                        lastId = purchaseList.get(purchaseList.size()-1).getPurchaseid();
                    }
                String subString = lastId.substring(1,4);
                int realId = Integer.parseInt(subString) +1;
            return realId;   
         }

public int GeneratePdid(){
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Purchasedetals.findAll");
    List<Purchasedetails> purchaseDetailsL = query.getResultList();
    String lastId = null;


                    if(!purchaseDetailsL.isEmpty()){
                        lastId = purchaseDetailsL.get(purchaseDetailsL.size()-1).getPurchasedetailid();
                    }
                String subString = lastId.substring(2,6);
                int realId = Integer.parseInt(subString) +1;
            return realId;   

}
```

HTML :

```
  <h1>Purchase</h1>
    <form  action="../PurchaseCreate" method="post">

        <p>Please enter the fields below to make your purchase</p>
        <p>
            Stock ID :
            <input type ="text" name ="stock">&nbsp;
        </p>
        <p>Quantity :
            <input type="text" name="quantity">&nbsp;
        </p>
            <input type="submit" name="create" class ="button" value="Add into cart">

    </form>
```

JSP :

```
 <% List<Purchasedetails> list = (List<Purchasedetails>)request.getAttribute("purchased"); %>
     <% List<Stocks> listPrice = (List<Stocks>)request.getAttribute("listPrice"); %>
     <% int size= list.size(); %>
     <%! String pDID = "";%>
     <%! int pDIDno = 0; %>
     <%! String pDIDSub = ""; %>
     <%! String pDIDreal = ""; %>
     <body>
          <% if (size != 1){ %>
     <% pDID = list.get(list.size()-1).getPurchasedetailid(); %>
     <% pDIDSub = pDID.substring(2, 6); %>
     <% pDIDno = Integer.parseInt(pDIDSub) + (size-1);}%>
     <% if(pDIDno<10)
                 pDIDreal = "PD0000"+pDIDno;
            else if(pDIDno<100)
                 pDIDreal = "PD000"+pDIDno;       
            else if(pDIDno<1000)
                 pDIDreal = "PD00"+pDIDno;
            else if(pDIDno<10000)
                 pDIDreal = "PD0"+pDIDno;
            else if(pDIDno<100000)
                 pDIDreal = "PD"+pDIDno;

                  list.get(list.size()-1).setPurchasedetailid(pDIDreal);
     %>
   <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Purchase Details ID</th>
                    <th>Stock ID</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <% for (int i = 1; i <list.size(); i++) { %>

                <tr>
                    <td><%= i-1 %></td>
                    <td><%= list.get(i).getPurchasedetailid() %></td>
                    <td><%= list.get(i).getStockid()  %></td>
                    <td><%= list.get(i).getOrderqty() %></td>
                    <td><%= listPrice.get(i).getStockprice() %></td>
                </tr>
                <% i++;%>
                <% } %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are invoking dispatcher in try/catch block. In the catch block you are doing nothing but logging the exception. If you move a code with dispatcher out of the try/catch block then it should dispatch even if you has errors in it. Change your code with

```java
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PurchaseCreate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} 

RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/MemberAccess/PurchaseCreateM.jsp");
   rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I don't see any changes though. It still a blank page.

Comment: What kind of changes are you looking?

Comment: cause I set attributes and get attributes, so if it connects to the jsp, shouldnt the table be shown ?

Comment: No, you've mistaken. If your code is throwing exceptions while communication with database you aren't populating properties.

Comment: @user3900009 Don't use scriptlets in JSP. Getters and setters not enough to display a table, but using with EL you can populate it with the foreach tag.